# update a variable without return its value in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensorflow graph (placeholder input, then some operations, finally update a variable in the graph using `tf.scatter_add()`).

I know that the `sess.run(tensor)` would return the value of the "tensor". In my case, the "tensor" is very large; I only need to update its value in the graph, and don't need its value.

So, any ideas? I can't find a novel solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing the `Tensor` as an argument to `run`, you can provide the corresponding `Operation`, which will execute the operation but not return anythingreturn `None` but execute the operation nonetheless (details in [documentation for `Session.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run))

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var = tf.Variable(1)
add = tf.assign_add(var, 1)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# Will print 'None' since running add.op will not return a value
print sess.run(add.op)
# Prints 3 since running the Tensor returns the value
print sess.run(add)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. It's a great help.